# 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysqlite, pysqlcipher

I am attempting to install the `pysqlite` module for `Python 2.7` on my `Windows 10` computer. I issued the following command:

```
pip install pysqlite
```

The installation ran as usual until it hit an error:

> c:\users\xaresys\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-xleoab\pysqlite\src\connection.h(33) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Users\xaresys\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

I also tried to install a similar module, `pysqlcipher`, which hit the same error. Do I need to install anything before installing this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the sqlite3 library itself? If so, did you install it from source, or with a binary installer? You'll need the source (development) version of the sqlite3 library.

Comment: Depending on how Python is installed on your machine, you may be able to simply use the built-in `sqlite3` module instead.

Comment: I have not installed any sqlite3 related files on my computer before. Is there a specific way I must install sqlite3 to work with pysqlcipher?

Comment: First, check if you can import sqlite3 on your Python prompt?

Comment: NB: did your question change from "attempting to install pysqlite" to "attempting to install pysqlcipher"?

Comment: At first I was trying to install pysqlcipher, but since that didn't work, I thought it needed pysqlite as a dependency. Then when I tried to install that, it threw the error in the OP. I guess I should've included that in the post.

Comment: You got its solution or not?

Comment: I have not @suv.

Comment: Please try to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53949490/10520161)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing Visual C++ binaries which are required to install some packages. Follow instructions here: https://github.com/develersrl/gccwinbinaries

Comment: its not woking for me, I am having the same error while trying to run "pip install pysqlcipher"