# Error while Installing sqlite using pip on Python 2.7.13

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, pysqlite

I am trying to install pysqlite using pip but it keeps giving me an error:

> Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory

I'm using Windows 10 OS 64 bit. Python version 2.7.13. I'm trying to install using pip. (pip install pysqlite)

I'm unable to share the error screenshot so I have copied the complete error code below. If anyone can help me, that will be great.
Thank you.

The complete cmd looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Who Are You>pip install pysqlite
Collecting pysqlite
  Using cached pysqlite-2.8.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pysqlite
  Running setup.py install for pysqlite ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\whoare~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-0ju9tj\\pysqlite\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\whoare~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-0cieyz-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2
    copying lib\dbapi2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2
    copying lib\dump.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2
    copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    copying lib\test\dbapi.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    copying lib\test\dump.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    copying lib\test\factory.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    copying lib\test\hooks.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    copying lib\test\regression.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    copying lib\test\transactions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    copying lib\test\types.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    copying lib\test\userfunctions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    copying lib\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test
    running build_ext
    building 'pysqlite2._sqlite' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src
    C:\Users\Who Are You\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite2.dbapi2\" -I'{' -Iis -Inot -Irecognized -Ias -Ian -Iinternal -Ior -Iexternal -Icommand, -Ioperable -Iprogram -Ior -Ibatch -Ifile. -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcsrc/module.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/module.obj
    module.c
    c:\users\who are you\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-0ju9tj\pysqlite\src\connection.h(33) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Who Are You\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\whoare~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-0ju9tj\\pysqlite\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\whoare~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-0cieyz-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\whoare~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-0ju9tj\pysqlite\
```

Screenshot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyi1G.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it this way:

1. Create a temporary directory *C:\sqlite*
2. Copy the files *lib.exe*, *link.exe* and *mspdb80.dll* to *C:\sqlite* from:

   - For X86 build: *%LocalAppData%\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin*
   - For X64 build: *%LocalAppData%\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin\amd64*
3. Download amalgamated source code and precompiled binaries for Windows (32-bit or 64-bit DLL files) archives from [SQLite website](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
4. Extract the binary files archive (*sqlite3.dll* and *sqlite3.def*) to *C:\sqlite*
5. Open Windows PowerShell in *C:\sqlite* and run:

   - For X86 build: `.\lib.exe /DEF:sqlite3.def /MACHINE:X86`
   - For X64 build: `.\lib.exe /DEF:sqlite3.def /MACHINE:X64`
6. Copy the created *sqlite3.lib* file to *C:\Python27\libs*
7. From the amalgamated source code archive extract *sqlite3.h* and *sqlite3ext.h* to *C:\Python27\include*
8. Run `pip install pysqlite`

Comment: didn't work, Win10 x64, python 2.7.18. Still the same error: `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory`. Weird thing is, that I can `import sqlite3` just fine. What do I do?

Answer (score -1):

As far as i can remember sqlite3 is inbuilt in python2.x and python3.x

Comment: The question does not concern installing `sqlite3`.